# Why do my content divs render differently from the server on a particular computer?

Tags: html, css-position

I am trying to design a site with a header/banner, three columns, and a footer.  I have been playing with it for over a week trying to get everything positioned properly, and finally found something that seemed to work.

I uploaded it to the server, but the right column displays below the container for the columns.  I thought this was a server issue, but it appears 'correctly' on my phone, on my work computer (IE), and on another laptop in the house.  The only time the display is wonky is loading the site on my laptop.

What could be causing my particular browser on my particular computer to display it incorrectly from the server? Note: it displays fine while developing from a local folder.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Internet was out last night, so I had to enter this on mobile.  Anyways, here are my data points...

- On my local machine's directory (Win 7), any browser; displays as expected.

The following are from the web server.

- On my phone (Android); displays as expected.
- On my GF's laptop (Win 8 and Chrome); displays as expected.
- On my work machine (Win 7 and IE11); displays as expected.
- On my laptop (Win7 and Chrome in Incognito mode); displays as expected.
- On my crappy 12 yr old PC (WinXP and Chrome in Incognito mode); displays as expected.

Here are the failures (viewing from server).

- On my laptop (Win7 and Chrome in normal mode); right column displays below the container, regardless of screen size/zoom.
- On my PC (WinXP and Chrome in normal mode); right column displays below the container, regardless of screen size/zoom.

Cleared the cache, site is one html file and one css at this point.  Validated both html and css via w3schools.

So this may help troubleshoot the problem; it may be a chrome setting or extension that is unavailable in Incognito.  I would appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: have you tried flushing thebrowser-cache (CTRL+F5) ?

Comment: Server has nothing to do with it. Maybe you didn't uploaded all the scripts/stylesheets to it? Check your console for errors.

Comment: @Vucko How do I check for errors?  I run the developer tools and turn various style elements on and off, but I don't see any difference.  At one point I accidentally got it working, but resizing the screen hosed it again.